# How do I list all my own questions?

Tags: discussion, lists, questions

There are hundreds of pages explaining how to *search* your own questions, or answers to them, but nothing that I can see about just getting a **list** of them. Some answers suggested using the Advanced Search, but that seems to apply only when you want to search for content.

I have probably missed it, but I'd be grateful if someone could point me at it.

Maybe it should be proposed as an enhancement, something like a profile menu item as it is with some other Q&A software, or even just a button beside your avatar "List own posts"

Comment: Well, it's not right under your avatar, but from there it's just a couple of clicks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/355/peter-flynn?tab=questions. But this is more a question for Meta than for the main site.

Comment: In the search bar, type `user:me is:question` to view a list of all your questions. `is:answer` lists all your answers. Just `user:me` lists all your posts.

Comment: Hah! Thank you! I knew there would be a simple answer that I had missed. In three months, of course, I won't be able to find this post again and I'll have forgotten what to type :-)  The tab in my profile is great, but wholly non-obvious because I don't see a line of undistinguished words as tabs. Someone needs to do some more usability testing on SE, I think. Can someone make an answer I can vote for, or should I just trash the question?

Answer (score 5):

There's a list of questions in your profile:

[image]

There's one direct link which works for all users: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions. It will automatically redirect to your own questions. Alternatively, you can combine the two [search options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/searching) `user:me` and `is:q` to search for 'posts by yourself' which 'are questions'; this might be useful when you want to combined it with e.g. `created:1y..` which filters on posts from the last 365 days.